# Error in StructField(a,StringType,false). It is false and should be true

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, scalatest

I have this error in my Scala test:

```
StructType(StructField(a,StringType,true), StructField(b,StringType,true), StructField(c,StringType,true), StructField(d,StringType,true), StructField(e,StringType,true), StructField(f,StringType,true), StructField(NewColumn,StringType,false)) did not equal StructType(StructField(a,StringType,true), StructField(b,StringType,true), StructField(c,StringType,true), StructField(d,StringType,true), StructField(e,StringType,true), StructField(f,StringType,true), StructField(NewColumn,StringType,true))

ScalaTestFailureLocation: com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.TestSuite$class at (TestSuite.scala:13)

Expected :StructType(StructField(a,StringType,true), StructField(b,StringType,true), StructField(c,StringType,true), StructField(d,StringType,true), StructField(e,StringType,true), StructField(f,StringType,true), StructField(NewColumn,StringType,true))

Actual   :StructType(StructField(a,StringType,true), StructField(b,StringType,true), StructField(c,StringType,true), StructField(d,StringType,true), StructField(e,StringType,true), StructField(f,StringType,true), StructField(NewColumn,StringType,false))
```

Last `StructField` is `false` when it should be `true` and I do not why. This true means that the schema accepts null values.

And this is my test:

```
val schema1 = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
val df = List(("a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1"),
  ("a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2"))
  .toDF(schema1: _*)

val schema2 = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "NewColumn")

val dfExpected = List(("a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1", "a1_b1_c1_d1_e1_f1"),
  ("a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2", "a2_b2_c2_d2_e2_f2")).toDF(schema2: _*)

val transformer = KeyContract("NewColumn", schema1)
val newDf = transformer(df)
newDf.columns should contain ("NewColumn")
assertDataFrameEquals(newDf, dfExpected)
```

And this is KeyContract:

```
case class KeyContract(tempColumn: String, columns: Seq[String],
                       unsigned: Boolean = true) extends Transformer {

  override def apply(input: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    val inputModif = columns.foldLeft(input) { (tmpDf, columnName) =>
      tmpDf.withColumn(columnName, when(col(columnName).isNull,
        lit("")).otherwise(col(columnName)))
    }

    inputModif.withColumn(tempColumn, concat_ws("_", columns.map(col): _*))
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `concat_ws` never returns `null` and the resulting field is marked as not nullable.

If you want to use a second `DataFrame` as a reference, you'll have to use schema and `Rows`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

val dfExpected = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(
  Row("a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1", "a1_b1_c1_d1_e1_f1"),
  Row("a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2", "a2_b2_c2_d2_e2_f2")
)), StructType(schema2.map { c => StructField(c, StringType, c != "NewColumn") }))
```

This way the last column won't be nullable:

```
dfExpected.printSchema
root
 |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |-- d: string (nullable = true)
 |-- e: string (nullable = true)
 |-- f: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NewColumn: string (nullable = false)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for being responsive and quickly fixing problems with the question.